# State machine of a nondeterministic PDA that recognizes the language

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation, pushdown-automaton

L = {a^i b^j c^k d^l | where l = i -j and i, j, k, l >= 0}

I'm trying to draw non-deterministic PDA for this but struggling to do so. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXBUW.jpg

So far I have been able to push a, and pop a for every b as an input. Any help?

Comment: If `l = i - j` then `i = j + l`, right? Which means that after you pop `a`s matching `b`s and ignore any number of `c`s....

Comment: @rici Sorry what? how do I make sure that the number of d's is the same as a and b? Could you draw something for me? that would help

Comment: I think that was enough of a hint. Try completing the sentence. Or play with a few sample inputs on paper. To be even more obvious, if you have a correct input ending with `l` `d`s, how many `a`s are on the stack once you've finished with the `b`s?

Comment: Just one? So if the string is aabd, then after popping a for every input b, it will be an a will be remaining and so can we say that for every d, pop the remaining a?

Comment: `l` is a lousy variable name. But I think you've got it. Try it out with pencil and paper :-)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YVx5rbg It still rejects the correct string :( What am I missing? Here, I'm popping a for every input of d.

Comment: @rici     https://imgur.com/a/XUv6cN3 I think I fixed it but now it is not non-deterministic. How do you suggest I make it nondeterministic?

Comment: I'm sure you're not required to have non-determinism. NPDA is a class of automata which it is allowed (not required) for states to have more than one applicable transition. DPDAs are a subset of NPDAs; in a sense, determinism is a special case. I suggest you discuss this with your professor or TA. Also, there might be more than one `c`.

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer to make your deterministic PDA nondeterministic, add a dead state and a lambda transition to it from the start state. Voila! Now your PDA is nondeterministic.